# Unlinked buttons and link buttons don't display tap animation/state change in jQuery Mobile

Tags: mobile, button, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use an unlinked button in a mobile app using jQuery Mobile. I still want the button to be tappable but instead of the default ajax behavior I'd like to use my own.

However when I tap a button that isn't linked to something it doesn't give any feedback. That is to say the CSS doesn't change to the pressed state and then back again. When I tap a link that has a valid href or is inside a form it works.

Oddly enough clicking links in my desktop browser does invoke a change although it isn't the same as tapping a button. With the default CSS package buttons will turn blue momentarily when tapping them to submit a form or proceed to the next page. When I click on them on my desktop they go to hover state which is gray so it appears this isn't really working on any browser.

Does anyone know how to get a simple button to respond to a tap even if the button doesn't actually link anywhere?

EDIT: Here's some code to try I tried this on both iOS and Android with the same result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <title>My Page</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-beta.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div data-role="page" id="startpage">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
                <h1>Button Test</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <button id="test1">Test 1</button>
                <button data-role="button" id="test2">Test 2</button>
                <a data-role="button" id="test3">Test 3</a>
                <a data-role="button" href="" id="test4">No href</a>
                <a data-role="button" href="#" id="test5">href=#</a>
                <a data-role="button" href="#page2" id="test6">This works because it's linked</a>
                <form method="get" action="index2.html">
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
                    <button type="submit" value="No tap change here either"></button>
                </form>
            </div><!-- /content -->
        </div><!-- /page -->

        <div data-role="page" id="page2">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
                <h1>Page 2</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">Linked buttons work</div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Could you provide some code?

Comment: Yup added an example. Even the form submitting button doesn't change to the tapped state.

Comment: this works on most: http://jsfiddle.net/Wgu9v/

Answer (score 1):

OK I ended up filing a bug in the jQuery Mobile issue tracker and it appears to be a known issue.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5009
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4469

The workaround is to use a link button like so:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-role="button">Click me</a>
```

With that the button will give feedback to the user even though it doesn't actually go anywhere or do anything.

They are looking into fixing this in v1.3.